# Building a secure anonymous uploader

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, amazon-s3

I want to build a website in which people can upload files to my S3 bucket via a rails app. I want the upload to be encrypted so that I have no knowledge of what is being uploaded and I want only the user to have the key to decrypt it.

Could someone give me some suggestions on how to go about this or some methods of achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

You can only encrypt it localy, everything else on the serverside (or even the ISP) can be manipulated somehow what is delivered

Answer (score 0):

Lichtamberg is right, the best and most secure way would be for the user to do it clientside. Perhaps you could tell them what encryption types are accepted (such as GPG) and provide instructions for doing so, or recommend tools that might make it easier.

You could probably enforce this in your code by checking whether an uploaded file is encrypted, and rejecting it if not. The check would be similar to an image upload feature that rejects non-image files, for instance.